# Problema na criação da tabela em javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa noite, pessoal! Estou com um problema no meu código em javascript, ele deveria criar uma tabela com os campos que eu preencho... Porém na hora em que eu aperto para adicionar, não adiciona os valores na tabela... Se alguém poder me ajudar na resolução desse problema desde já agradeço.
Se estiver faltando mais alguma explicação estarei a disposição para explicar!!

Segue abaixo o código em HTML E JAVASCRIPT.

CÓDIGO Html

```
<body>
//formação dos campos da tabela//

<form action="" class="tabela">

    <label id="etiqueta" for="equipamento">Equipamento</label>
    <input required  type="text" name="equipamento" placeholder="Digite seu Equipamento">
    <br>
    <label for="modelo">Modelo</label>
    <input required type="text" name="modelo" placeholder="Digite sua Modelo">
    <br>
    <label for="data" >Data</label>
    <input required type="date" name="data" placeholder="Digite a Data da retira">
    <br>
    <label for="chamado" >Numero do chamado</label>
    <input required type="number" name="chamado" placeholder="Digite o chamado referente o equepamento ">
    <br>
    <label for="modelo">Quantidade de Saída</label>
    <input required type="number" name="quantidade" placeholder="Digite a Quantidade">
    <br>
    <button id="adicionar_dados">Adicionar Linha</button>

</form>
<div class="alerta"></div>

<hr>

//inicio da tabela//

<table border="2px solid" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Equipamento</td>
            <td>Modelo</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Numero do chamado</td>
            <td>Quantidade de Saída</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody >

    </tbody>
    <hr>
</table>
```

Código javascript:

```
// funções botão

botao_excluir.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var tr = this.parentNode;
    var tb = tr.parentNode;
  tb.removeChild(tr);

});

botao_editar.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var tr = this.parentNode;       

    for(var i =0; i< tr.children.length -2; i++){
            var td = tr.children[i];
        if(td.children[0].tagName = 'textarea')
        td.children[0].disabled = false;
    }

});

inputEquipamento.setAttribute('disabled',true);
inputModelo.setAttribute('disabled',true);
inputData.setAttribute('disabled',true);
inputChamado.setAttribute('disabled',true);
inputQuantidade.setAttribute('disabled',true);

//variaveis

var botao_adicionar = document.querySelector("#adicionar_dados");
var campo_equipamento = document.querySelector("input[name='equipamento']");
var campo_modelo = document.querySelector("input[name='modelo']");
var campo_data = document.querySelector("input[name='data']");
var campo_chamado = document.querySelector("input[name='chamado']");
var campo_quantidade = document.querySelector("input[name='quantidade']");

var corpo_tabela = document.querySelector("tbody");

var contTab=0;

//funções tabela

function TabelaDinamica(equipamento,modelo,data,chamado,quantidade)
{

        this.equipamento=equipamento;
        this.modelo=modelo;
        this.data=data;
        this.chamado=chamado;
        this.quantidade=quantidade;


        this.mostrar_dados=function() 
        {
        console.log(" equipamento é"+this.equipamento+
            "o modelo é"+this.modelo+
            "a data é "+this.data+
            "o chamado"+this.chamado+
            "e a quantidade"+this.quantidade)
        }

this.criar_linha_tabela = function()
{

        var linha = document.createElement("tr");
        var campo_equipamento = document.createElement("td");
        var campo_modelo = document.createElement("td");
        var campo_data = document.createElement("td");
        var campo_chamado = document.createElement("td");
        var campo_quantidade = document.createElement("td");

        var inputEquipamento = document.createElement("textarea");
        var inputModelo = document.createElement("textarea");
        var inputData = document.createElement("textarea");
        var inputChamado = document.createElement("textarea");
        var inputQuantidade = document.createElement("textarea");

    inputEquipamento.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputModelo.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputData.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputChamado.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    inputQuantidade.setAttribute('disabled',true);


        var texto_equipamento = document.createTextNode(this.equipamento);
        var texto_modelo = document.createTextNode(this.modelo);
        var texto_data = document.createTextNode(this.data);
        var texto_chamado = document.createTextNode(this.chamado);
        var texto_quantidade = document.createTextNode(this.quantidade);


        inputEquipamento.appendChild(texto_equipamento);
        inputModelo.appendChild(texto_modelo);
        inputData.appendChild(texto_data);
        inputChamado.appendChild(texto_chamado);
        inputQuantidade.appendChild(texto_quantidade);

        campo_quantidade.appendChild(inputQuantidade);
        campo_chamado.appendChild(inputChamado);
        campo_data.appendChild(inputData);
        campo_modelo.appendChild(inputModelo);
        campo_equipamento.appendChild(inputEquipamento);

        var botao_editar = document.createElement("input");
        botao_editar.setAttribute('type','submit');
        botao_editar.setAttribute('value','editar');

        var botao_excluir = document.createElement("input");
        botao_excluir.setAttribute('type','submit');
        botao_excluir.setAttribute('value','excluir');  



        linha.appendChild(campo_equipamento);
        linha.appendChild(campo_modelo);
        linha.appendChild(campo_data);
        linha.appendChild(campo_chamado);
        linha.appendChild(campo_quantidade);
        linha.appendChild(botao_editar);
        linha.appendChild(botao_excluir);

        corpo_tabela.appendChild(linha);


        botao_excluir.addEventListener('click',function(){
            var tr = this.parentNode;
            var tb = tr.parentNode;
          tb.removeChild(tr);

        });

//função botão

        botao_editar.addEventListener('click', function(){
                var tr = this.parentNode;            
            for(var i =0; i< tr.children.length -2; i++){
                    var td = tr.children[i];
                if(td.children[0].tagName = 'textarea')
                td.children[0].disabled = false;
            }

        });


    }

  };

function adicionar_dados(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    nova_tabelaDinamica = new TabelaDinamica(campo_equipamento.value,campo_modelo.value,campo_data.value,campo_chamado.value,campo_quantidade.value);

    nova_tabelaDinamica.criar_linha_tabela();

    nova_tabelaDinamica.mostrar_dados();


};

botao_adicionar.addEventListener('click',adicionar_dados);
```

Comment: O básico do seu código sequer está funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

`botao_excluir`, `botao_editar`, `inputEquipamento`, `inputModelo`, `inputData`, `inputChamado` e `inputQuantidade` não estão definidos quando a página é carregada eles são gerados dinamicamente dentro da tabela dinâmica e qualquer referência a eles, drante o carregamento da página, gera erro fazendo com que o script termine e não carregue o event handler `adicionar_dados`.

Para corrigir eu apenas comentei esse trecho de código:

```
// funções botão

botao_excluir.addEventListener('click', function()  {
  var tr = this.parentNode;
  var tb = tr.parentNode;
  tb.removeChild(tr);

});

botao_editar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tr = this.parentNode;

  for (var i = 0; i < tr.children.length - 2; i++) {
    var td = tr.children[i];
    if (td.children[0].tagName = 'textarea')
      td.children[0].disabled = false;
  }

});

inputEquipamento.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputModelo.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputData.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputChamado.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputQuantidade.setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

Segue seu código funcionando:

```js
/* Trecho comentado pois gera sucessivos erros de referência não definida
// funções botão

botao_excluir.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tr = this.parentNode;
  var tb = tr.parentNode;
  tb.removeChild(tr);

});

botao_editar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tr = this.parentNode;

  for (var i = 0; i < tr.children.length - 2; i++) {
    var td = tr.children[i];
    if (td.children[0].tagName = 'textarea')
      td.children[0].disabled = false;
  }

});

inputEquipamento.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputModelo.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputData.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputChamado.setAttribute('disabled', true);
inputQuantidade.setAttribute('disabled', true);

*/

//variaveis

var botao_adicionar = document.querySelector("#adicionar_dados");
var campo_equipamento = document.querySelector("input[name='equipamento']");
var campo_modelo = document.querySelector("input[name='modelo']");
var campo_data = document.querySelector("input[name='data']");
var campo_chamado = document.querySelector("input[name='chamado']");
var campo_quantidade = document.querySelector("input[name='quantidade']");

var corpo_tabela = document.querySelector("tbody");

var contTab = 0;

//funções tabela

function TabelaDinamica(equipamento, modelo, data, chamado, quantidade) {

  this.equipamento = equipamento;
  this.modelo = modelo;
  this.data = data;
  this.chamado = chamado;
  this.quantidade = quantidade;


  this.mostrar_dados = function() {
    console.log(" equipamento é" + this.equipamento +
      "o modelo é" + this.modelo +
      "a data é " + this.data +
      "o chamado" + this.chamado +
      "e a quantidade" + this.quantidade)
  }

  this.criar_linha_tabela = function() {

    var linha = document.createElement("tr");
    var campo_equipamento = document.createElement("td");
    var campo_modelo = document.createElement("td");
    var campo_data = document.createElement("td");
    var campo_chamado = document.createElement("td");
    var campo_quantidade = document.createElement("td");

    var inputEquipamento = document.createElement("textarea");
    var inputModelo = document.createElement("textarea");
    var inputData = document.createElement("textarea");
    var inputChamado = document.createElement("textarea");
    var inputQuantidade = document.createElement("textarea");

    inputEquipamento.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    inputModelo.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    inputData.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    inputChamado.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    inputQuantidade.setAttribute('disabled', true);


    var texto_equipamento = document.createTextNode(this.equipamento);
    var texto_modelo = document.createTextNode(this.modelo);
    var texto_data = document.createTextNode(this.data);
    var texto_chamado = document.createTextNode(this.chamado);
    var texto_quantidade = document.createTextNode(this.quantidade);


    inputEquipamento.appendChild(texto_equipamento);
    inputModelo.appendChild(texto_modelo);
    inputData.appendChild(texto_data);
    inputChamado.appendChild(texto_chamado);
    inputQuantidade.appendChild(texto_quantidade);

    campo_quantidade.appendChild(inputQuantidade);
    campo_chamado.appendChild(inputChamado);
    campo_data.appendChild(inputData);
    campo_modelo.appendChild(inputModelo);
    campo_equipamento.appendChild(inputEquipamento);

    var botao_editar = document.createElement("input");
    botao_editar.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    botao_editar.setAttribute('value', 'editar');

    var botao_excluir = document.createElement("input");
    botao_excluir.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    botao_excluir.setAttribute('value', 'excluir');



    linha.appendChild(campo_equipamento);
    linha.appendChild(campo_modelo);
    linha.appendChild(campo_data);
    linha.appendChild(campo_chamado);
    linha.appendChild(campo_quantidade);
    linha.appendChild(botao_editar);
    linha.appendChild(botao_excluir);

    corpo_tabela.appendChild(linha);


    botao_excluir.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var tr = this.parentNode;
      var tb = tr.parentNode;
      tb.removeChild(tr);

    });

    //função botão

    botao_editar.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var tr = this.parentNode;
      for (var i = 0; i < tr.children.length - 2; i++) {
        var td = tr.children[i];
        if (td.children[0].tagName = 'textarea')
          td.children[0].disabled = false;
      }

    });


  }

};

function adicionar_dados(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  nova_tabelaDinamica = new TabelaDinamica(campo_equipamento.value, campo_modelo.value, campo_data.value, campo_chamado.value, campo_quantidade.value);

  nova_tabelaDinamica.criar_linha_tabela();

  nova_tabelaDinamica.mostrar_dados();


};

botao_adicionar.addEventListener('click', adicionar_dados);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  //formação dos campos da tabela//

  <form action="" class="tabela">

    <label id="etiqueta" for="equipamento">Equipamento</label>
    <input required type="text" name="equipamento" placeholder="Digite seu Equipamento">
    <br>
    <label for="modelo">Modelo</label>
    <input required type="text" name="modelo" placeholder="Digite sua Modelo">
    <br>
    <label for="data">Data</label>
    <input required type="date" name="data" placeholder="Digite a Data da retira">
    <br>
    <label for="chamado">Numero do chamado</label>
    <input required type="number" name="chamado" placeholder="Digite o chamado referente o equepamento ">
    <br>
    <label for="modelo">Quantidade de Saída</label>
    <input required type="number" name="quantidade" placeholder="Digite a Quantidade">
    <br>
    <button id="adicionar_dados">Adicionar Linha</button>

  </form>
  <div class="alerta"></div>

  <hr> //inicio da tabela//

  <table border="2px solid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Equipamento</td>
        <td>Modelo</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Numero do chamado</td>
        <td>Quantidade de Saída</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    <hr>
  </table>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: augusto muito obrigado pela ajuda. ainda estou iniciando meus estudos na linguagem poderia me explicar como posso encontrar meu erros mais facilmente ?

Comment: É experiência. Eu já vi bugs de todas as espécies. Com passar do tempo vai surgindo um padrão na mente. O que ajuda? Trabalhar em equipe, ajuda bastante. Trocar idéias sobre o código é uma experiência enriquecedora. Incorporar boas práticas a codificação.... parece conselho de avó, são coisas simples mas os erros moram nos detalhes e nos fundamentos.